# Java - Scanner declaration

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I am a very new to Java.
Here is a very simple switch method.

When a user types String here it will throw an error and the catch will call this method back again as coded.

and here is my question about Scanner.

I realized that I needed to put those

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

in the "try" body, if I wanted it to tell me to physically type again, but why is that? Why typing

`int select = sc.nextInt();`

is not enough?

Would

`int select1 = sc.nextInt();` and

`int select2 = sc.nextInt();` be the same because it has the same "sc" instance ?

```
 public void reAsk(){
  System.out.println("Type a number")
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  try {
        int select = sc.nextInt();
        switch (select) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;


    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please type int");
        reAsk();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You have to put it in the `try` block because if you enter something that isn't an `int` then it will throw an error. In your `catch` block you recall the method so that it will in essence keep on calling the method as long as the input is invalid

Comment: 2. No they wouldn't be the same. The `nextInt()` function consumes part of the input. So if you simply typed 5 and then 6, the first call to `nextInt()` would consume the five, resolve it to the first variable, and then the second call to `nextInt()` would consume the 6 and resolve it to the second variable, making the two variables `5` and `6` respectively

Comment: Please don't call the method `reAsk` in itself again. This will increase the method nesting, possibly slowing down your app because the other `reAsk` method didn't yet finish but call another. Instead, wrap a loop around your logic and repeat the loop until the input is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `nextInt()` (or any `next()` method) will simply try to read the next token (in the cast of `nextInt()`, a possible sign (+/-) and digits) in the stream, eg: the standard input.

If you were to type: 0 1 2, then each successive calls to `nextInt()` would return 0, 1 and 2.

To continue on the `Scanner`, you don't need to create a `Scanner` each time the `reAsk` method is called, nor that you need to use recursion in such trivial case (unless it is for an exercise): you can reuse it but you must be wary of characters left in the buffer in case of errors.

For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
try {    
  ...
  int select;
  for (;;) {
    try {
      select = sc.nextInt();
      break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ignored) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  // select is always initialized in that case
  switch (select) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This will do an infinite loop because `sc` fails to read an `int` and there are still invalid `int` character in the buffer (ex: `'a 1'`).

You may use `sc.next()` to advance (this will discard next token, eg: `a` in the example above).

But it would be wiser to use `sc.hasNextInt()` in that case:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!sc.hasNextInt() && sc.hasNext()) {
  sc.next(); // advance / discard the invalid token
}

// we don't care about result of hasNext() here.
int select = sc.nextInt();
```

As said in the comment above, we don't test `hasNext()` for two main reasons:

- if `hasNext()` returns `false`, then it is more likely that the stream ended. You may want to call `hasNextInt()` before `nextInt()`, and if it returns `false`, properly end your method. This example will fail with a `NoSuchElementException`.
- `System.in` would probably end only if it is redirected (eg: `java Main < foobar.txt`, `echo a | java Main`) or if some sequence is called (I don't remember but I believe it is Ctrl + Z) or if you closed (in)directly in Java (`System.in.close()`).

**Note:** in most case, resource such as `Scanner`, are created in a *try-with-resources*, eg:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  ...
}
```

While it is good practice, this will close the `System.in` and you'll never be able to use it:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  String next = sc.next(); // again, without hasNext().
}
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  String next = sc.next(); // fail NoSuchElementException (stream is closed).
}
```

In your case, you may ignore the *try-with-resources*.

Answer (score 0):

Your findings are incorrect. I've fixed your code, hopefully this addresses your question:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void reAsk() {
    System.out.println("Type a number");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        int select = sc.nextInt();
        switch (select) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;

        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        reAsk();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reAsk();
    }

}
```

There is no need to initialize the scanner class inside the try catch. You simply had a few syntax errors. Firstly, in Java each statement must end in a semicolon, you neglected to add a semicolon after `System.out.println("Type a number")`.

Comment: What did you actually change? Looks like you copy pasted his code and added a main method to call the function which OP was not wondering why his code did not work...he was asking questions regarding scanner.

Comment: @AndrewG His code had syntax errors, I'm trying to show that you do not need to move the Scanner initialization into the try for the code to repeatedly ask the user for input.

Comment: You should explain all of the changes and why they were required. Just posting code is not helpful for learning.